# Random access to DocumentFile

Tags: android, file, random-access, randomaccessfile, storage-access-framework

How can I get Random Access to `DocumentFile`'s `OutputStream`, so that I can seek to any particular position and start writing from there onwards. Or if there's a way of appending to the existing content of a `DocumentFile`. The file is essentially going to be on an external SD Card, thus I have to use `DocumentFile` for this purpose.

In short, is there a `RandomAccessFile` for `DocumentFile` too?

Comment: For appending did you try: `getContentResolver().openOutputStream(docfile.getUri(), "wa");`. (Untested).

Comment: @greenapps Thanks, I haven't tried it. I was looking towards the OutputStream Methods, not in ContentResolver. It should work. Let me test.

Comment: How did it go ?

Comment: @dentex I just posted it as an answer. You can have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't actually answer the original question but was working for my requirement. I wanted to append the new data to existing DocumentFile and the method suggested by [greenapps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2108972/greenapps) was the one which solved it for me. (Thanks to him)

I just needed to open the output stream in `wa` mode to append.

```
getContentResolver().openOutputStream(docfile.getUri(), "wa");
```